# Why is GiB used insteed of GB

Tags: storage

I don't know where to ask this question so I posted it here.

I see that in Ubuntu the sign for Gigabytes, Megabyte etc are used as GiB, MiB etc. So my question is: What is the reason for using i between GB.

Comment: GB=1000 Gib=1024. Official ruling by the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Electrotechnical_Commission

Comment: This has no relation to Ubuntu. More a google thing

Comment: actually, it has. Ubuntu uses GiB in its notation, while Windows uses GB (for the same thing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1KB = 10^3 = 1000,
1KiB = 2^10 = 1024

1MB = 10^6 = 1000000,
1MiB = 2^20 = 1048576

and so on ;)

Comment: Case matters 1mb (one millibit) !=1MB (one megabyte)

Comment: @Sylwester hope its fine now :) thanks for mentioning.

Answer (score 1):

An KB is actually 1024 B. However, some people (like hard disk manufacturers) use 1 KB = 1000 B, because K means 1000 (like KG, KM) or in case of hard disk manufacturers because their hard drives appear to have more space (or that's what I would do). If you see KiB it is always 1024 B.