# Nautilus reports a different amount of space than fdisk does

Tags: nautilus, fdisk

I was saving some files to a USB and it said to me that I didn't have enough space available, so I deleted some files but Ubuntu wasn't detecting the freeing of space.

I changed to my Windows installation and ran a quick repair and it did work but the size of the partition got reduced, but when I reconnected the USB to my Linux installation, I was getting reported a higher storage amount than in Windows.

I attempted running `fdisk` and it did detect the real amount of storage, which is 14.9 GiB , but `nautilus` is detecting 16 GB, as shown on screenshots below :

[image: fdisk]

[image: nautilus]

How can I fix it?

PS. The USB partition is `sdb1`.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/452647/why-is-gib-used-insteed-of-gb  fdisk uses GibiBytes (x1024) where Nautilus uses GigaBytes (x1000).  See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibibyte

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is actually is in your question itself, you wrote

> [...]`fdisk` [...] did detect the real amount of storage, which is 14.9 **GiB** , but `nautilus` is detecting 16 **GB** [...]

Nautilus uses the [metric prefixes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix)  (1000 bytes = 1 kilobyte (KB), 1000 kilobytes = 1 megabyte (MB) etc.) whereas `fdisk` uses [binary prefixes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix)  (1024 bytes = 1 kibibyte (KiB), 1024 kibibytes = 1 mebibyte (MiB) etc.).
14.9 GiB = 14.9×1.024³ GB ≈ 15.99875 GB ≈ 16 GB, so it adds up.